# OS X - make ordinary SSH commands use SSH config

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, unix, openssh

Here is a (somewhat redacted) listing of my `~/.ssh/config` under OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard:

```
Host *
     IdentitiesOnly yes

Host foo1
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User foo1
     HostName example.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo1_rsa

Host foo2
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User foo2
     HostName example.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo2_rsa

# (and so on) 

Host bar1
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User bar1
     HostName example.org
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bar1_rsa

Host bar2
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User bar2
     HostName example.org
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bar2_rsa

# (and so on some more) 

Host github
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User git
     HostName github.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa

Host heroku
     IdentitiesOnly yes
     User git
     HostName heroku.com
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/heroku_rsa
```

Let's run a command to see if that works:

```
$ ssh github
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi sampablokuper! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

OK, first command works. Let's try a second command:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Uh-oh, second command didn't work.

**My question is: what can I do to make the second command above produce the same result as the first command?**

NB. Adding the `-v` option suggests that the second command fails because instead of offering Github's server the public key specified for git@github.com in `~/.ssh/config` (i.e. `~/.ssh/github_rsa`), it offers it `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `ssh git@github.com`, it's skipping your config file, since it doesn't have a corresponding **Host** configured, and instead relies on plain ssh -- which is likely loading `~/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of your Github key file, `~/.ssh/github_rsa`. (Note that if you had an existing *ssh-agent* running, then your command could perhaps utilize a previously loaded key. This might happen if you'd opened the Github desktop client.)

To allow your second command to work, duplicate your existing **Host** entry for `github`, changing the host to `github.com`. Now when you reference that host, ssh has a config to read out. (You could alternatively update the current **Host** entry with a wildcard pattern, e.g. `github*`.)

Here is some reference for ssh_config: http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config. The `-v` option is useful in determining whether the config, and which keys, if any, are being loaded.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the section, you can add more than one name to a single Host statement:  
  
`Host github  github.com  
     User git`

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using aviv's suggested variation on Brian's solution.